# How does this ruby custom accessor work

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, accessor, class-eval

So the method below in class_eval dynamically creates accessors for attributes defined at runtime.  It can be used, for example, to create configuration objects with attributes read from a config file (and unknown until runtime).  I understanding all of it except for the else branch.  If I am correct the else branch returns the attribute value (val[0]) if there is one value passed in *val.  However the way its written I would expect it to return an array (val) if there is more then one value passed in *var.  In particular, if I have something like the following:

```
value = 5
```

then from reading the code I would expect `@value to be [=,5]`.  However `@value` returns 5 and not the array [=,5].  How is this possible?

```
class Module
    def dsl_accessor(*symbols)
        symbols.each do |sym|
            class_eval %{
                def #{sym}(*val)
                    if val.empty?
                        @#{sym}
                    else
                         @#{sym} = val.size == 1 ? val[0] : val
                    end
                end
            }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equals sign is not an argument for the method, it's a part of the method name. Actually you can call an assignment like this:

```
value=(5)
```

So only the integer 5 is an argument for the function.

---

```
class Module
    def dsl_accessor(*symbols)
        symbols.each do |sym|
            class_eval %{
                def #{sym}
                  @#{sym}
                end
                def #{sym}=(val)
                  @#{sym} = val
                end
            }
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I understand that but again in @#{sym} = val.size == 1 ? val[0] : val @value will be set equal to val (which holds ["=",5]) so how isn't it the same as @value=["=",5] ?

Comment: Why do you expect val will holds ["=",5] ? If in your invocation
value = 5
has no '=' argument

For now in your module you have only getter method. Actually if you want create custom accessor you need create two methods. Something like in code which I add to answer

Comment: Or even simple: def dsl_accessor(*symbols); class_eval %{:attr_accessor :#{symbols.join(', :')}} ;end